# Osm Bonuspack shows that invalid response from server when I want to get the longitude and latitude

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap

It shows the error:

> Invalid response from server: HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests

I use a button to get the name what I want to search:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.find) {
     String keyword = name.getText().toString();
     new UpdateSearch().execute(keyword);
     find.setEnabled(false);
}
```

The following is the use of GeocoderNominatim in a AsyncTask:

```
    public class UpdateSearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        GeocoderNominatim coderNominatim = new GeocoderNominatim(
                MainActivity.this);
        List<Address> geoResults = null ;
        try {
            geoResults = coderNominatim.getFromLocationName(params[0], 3);
             Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa",String.valueOf(coderNominatim));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return geoResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> result) {...
```

And I got errors :

> 09-13 15:04:39.352: D/BONUSPACK(547):
>   GeocoderNominatim::getFromLocationName:http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&accept-language=zh&addressdetails=1&limit=3&q=%E6%95%85%E5%AE%AB
>       09-13 15:04:39.355: W/System(547): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
>       09-13 15:04:40.918: E/BONUSPACK(547): Invalid response from server: HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests

Some days ago, I can use the bonuspack and I got what I want. But recently the bonuspack becomes worse.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests` means you are performing too many requests from your IP address.

The Nominatim instance you are using is run by volunteers on donated resources. Please read the [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/), especially the part about the number of requests per second.

If you need to perform more requests then either [switch to a different Nominatim instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers) or [install your own Nominatim server](http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/Installation).

Comment: But I only want one place's address. And several days ago I can get the address by using it.

Comment: Wait some time and then try gain (by performing a single request only). Do you share your IP with other people? It could also be a temporarily problem of this Nominatim instance. Maybe you can tell osmbonuspack to use a different server.

Answer (score 0):

from [nominatim policies](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/)

> Provide a valid HTTP Referer or User-Agent identifying the application (stock User-Agents as set by http libraries will not do).

you have to setup an app specific useragent

```
String MY_USERAGENT = "com.beview.mygeoapp";
GeocoderNominatim coderNominatim = new GeocoderNominatim(
            MainActivity.this, MY_USERAGENT);
```